# How can I get property names from a ComObject in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, enumerate, comobject, object-properties

This code pulls summary information from an MSI or MSP file. I'm trying to figure out how to enumerate the property names, rather than just the property values, the below only outputs the value. How can I get the associated property name as well?

```
$directory = "xxxx";
$msiPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $workDir -Include "*.msi" , "*.msp" -Recurse | % {$_.FullName} ;
$installer = New-Object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer;
$database = $installer.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenDatabase", "InvokeMethod", $null, $installer, $($msiPath,0));
$summaryInfo = $database.GetType().InvokeMember("SummaryInformation", "GetProperty",$null , $database, $null);
$propertyCount = $summaryInfo.GetType().InvokeMember("PropertyCount", "GetProperty", $null, $summaryInfo, $null);
for ($i = 0; $i -le $propertyCount; $i++)
{
    Write-Host $i $summaryInfo.GetType().InvokeMember("Property", "GetProperty", $null, $summaryInfo, $i);  
    
}
```

Comment: Please disregard if I'm incorrect, but I believe you have to create the mapping to their corresponding *property name* yourself, seeing as COM objects usually work with IDs. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/summary-information-stream-property-set